# I have two arrays and I need to do a simple operation in one array depending on conditions of the other array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have two arrays `R` and `M`. In the first array, `R.shape = (10,7)`, each row corresponds to the state of an object and each column is the evolution of the object in time (10 objects in 7 time periods each). The second array `M` is a characteristic of each object **('C', 'SC','HS','HSDO')**.

`R = np.ones((10,7))`

```
  [[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

`M = ['C', 'C', 'HS', 'C', 'C', 'SC', 'SC', 'HSDO', 'HSDO', 'HSDO']`

I would like to know how can I modify the array `R` so I can add an x value to that row depending on the characteristic assigned by `M`?

For example: if I want `M=='C'`, the rows corresponding to `'C'`will add + 0.5.

```
  [[1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5]
   [1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5]
   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
   [1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5]
   [1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5]
   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
   [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

and like that with `'SC'` add 0.7, `'HS'` add 0.5 and `'HSDO'` add 0.3.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: What have you tried, and what was your result? A loop, np.where, [apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) for example? Please include code to make a [mcve]

Comment: This sounds like a `Pandas` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a dictionary mapping each string to the value to add, then looped through `M` to add the values to `R`:

```
d = {'C':.5, 'SC':.7, 'HS':.5, 'HSDO':.3}

for i, val in enumerate(M):
    R[i] += d[val]
```

Result:

```
array([[1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
       [1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
       [1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
       [1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
       [1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
       [1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7],
       [1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7],
       [1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3],
       [1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3],
       [1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3]])
```

You could also do:

```
R += np.array([d[m] for m in M])[:, None]
```